# AngularDart Owl Carousel

Tags: angular, owl-carousel, angular-dart

I am trying to implement owl carousel using Angular my code is as below

```
<section id="demos">
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of items">
                <carouselFixture [stream]="item.stream" *ngIf="item.viewModelType == 'ItemSummary'" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

[image: In the below image I had highlighted the area that is done using Owl Carousel]

The output of the Owl Carousel is weird, can anyone help me how to solve this problem. I had developed the application using Dart and Angular

Comment: It looks like a problem with your CSS which you didn't link. The fixture is using display:block which it appears you don't want.

Comment: Instead of using *ngFor if I do like this shown in the below code it is working perfectly....  <section id="demos">
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                Hello 1
            </div>
     <div class="item">
                Hello 2
            </div>
     <div class="item">
                Hello 3
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                Hello 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</section>

Comment: Can you try the equivalent with ngFor without the component? I still think it is the component host using block it counts as an html node.